# javascript jquery.getJSON weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been starting to experiment with javascript and jQuery. I was trying to create a class that would load a json file into a specified div, but I run into a behaviour I don't understand:

*NOTE: I know this code won't load anything into a div, it's just the shortest example I could find to show the behaviour I don't understand.*

```
function test(div) {
    this.div = div;
    _this = this;
    jQuery.getJSON('/example.json', null, function(data) {
        console.log(_this.div);
    });
}
```

when I run

```
a = new test("a"); 
b = new test("b");
```

I expected to see "ab" as the output, but the actual output is "bb".
However, if I allow for the first line to finish before calling the second one, then the expected output is shown. I'm confused!

Answer (score 5):

Your  `_this` is a global variable, add `var` before it.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/SQRwn/

By the way, your code would work fine if it were the following, but what you have here is probably not the code you're going to use...

```
function test(div) {
    jQuery.getJSON('/example.json', null, function(data) {
        console.log(div);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't include `var` before your variable it becomes a global variable:

```
_this = this;
```

shoudl be

```
var _this = this;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you didn't properly delcare the `_this` variable, and it is global. Change the line to this:

```
var _this = this;
```

With your code sample, though, you don't even need to cache `this`:

```
function test(div) {
    jQuery.getJSON('/example.json', null, function(data) {
        console.log(div);
    });
}
```